# Scheme operations within if condition

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, scheme, conditional-statements

Generally in Scheme  - `syntax: (if test consequent alternate)` .

I trying to do some operations within the `consequent` section , for example : *if true then set sum1 on 44 and return 1* .
In Scheme code its -

```
(if #t ( 
          (set! sum1 44)
          (if #t 1)
          ))
```

The above code doesn't works out and prompts -

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
   1
```

Comment: see my updated answer for an alternative solution to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scheme, parentheses are always used for application; you can't add extra parentheses for grouping.

Your `consequent` here is:

```
((set! sum1 44) (if #t 1))
```

The outer pair of parentheses makes Scheme attempt to use the result of `(set! sum1 44)` as a procedure, applying it to the result of `(if #t 1)`.

What (I think) you want is to evaluate the two expressions in sequence, and then return the result of the last one. The form to do this is `begin`, so it should be:

```
(begin (set! sum1 44) (if #t 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(if #t (begin 
          (set! sum1 44)
          (if #t 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Some interpreters (Racket, for instance) complain if you write an `if` without an `else` part. For dealing with this, and for avoiding the need to explicitly use a `begin` when more than one expression goes in the consequent part, it's better to use the [`when`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/when_unless.html?q=when&q=when#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/letstx-scheme..rkt%29._when%29%29=) special form (if available, because it's non-standard):

```
(when #t
  (set! sum1 44)
  (when #t 1))
```

In general, this is the structure of a `when` and its sibling `unless`:

```
(when <condition>    ; equivalent to (if <condition> (begin ...))
  <exp1>             ; consequent, no alternative
  <exp2>)

(unless <condition>  ; equivalent to (if (not <condition>) (begin ...))
  <exp1>             ; consequent, no alternative
  <exp2>)
```

If both the consequent and the alternative have more than one expression, you could use `if` with a `begin` in each part:

```
(if <condition>
    (begin     ; consequent
      <exp1>
      <exp2>)
    (begin     ; alternative
      <exp3>
      <exp4>))
```

... But it'd be more practical to use a `cond`, which implicitly uses a `begin` in each of its clauses:

```
(cond (<condition>
       <exp1>  ; consequent
       <exp2>)
      (else    ; alternative
       <exp3>
       <exp4>))
```